# Problema al trabajar con los atributos de una clase en python [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'derecha']

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, funciones, atributos

Tengo un problema al instanciar mi clase `nodoActual`: en mi función `ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz` todo va bien; al parecer si crea el objeto de forma correcta, pero cuando mando a llamar sus atributos `.derecha, .izquierda, .arriba, .abajo` en los `if()` me sale el siguiente error

```
**[AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'derecha']**
```

No entiendo muy bien que esta pasando y estaría totalmente agradecido si alguien se tomará el tiempo de ayudarme con esto ya le di mil vueltas.

A continuación dejo el código de mi clase `NodoPosicion` y todo lo relacionado con mi función `ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz`.

*Clase NodoPosicion*

````
class NodoPosicion:
def __init__(self, fila, columna, valor):
    self.fila = fila
    self.columna = columna 
    self.valor = valor
    self.derecha = None
    self.izquierda = None
    self.arriba = None
    self.abajo = None```
````

*Código de mi función*

````
#Función para recorrer todo mi matriz de nodos desde un nodo cualquiera elegido
def ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(self, origenFila, origenColumna, elementosRecorridos = []):
    nodoActual = NodoPosicion(0,0,0)
    nodoActual = self.getNodo(origenFila, origenColumna)
    if nodoActual in elementosRecorridos:
        return
    #Imprimir el peso de la arista - costo de ir un nodo a otro
    print(self.getPesoNodo(origenFila, origenColumna))
    print(type(nodoActual))
    elementosRecorridos.append(nodoActual)
    #Vecinos del grafo/nodo en la matriz
    print(type(nodoActual.derecha))
    if nodoActual.derecha != None:
        self.ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(nodoActual.derecha.fila, nodoActual.derecha.columna, elementosRecorridos)
    if nodoActual.izquierda != None:
        self.ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(nodoActual.izquierda.fila, nodoActual.izquierda.columna, elementosRecorridos)
    if nodoActual.arriba != None:
        self.ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(nodoActual.arriba.fila, nodoActual.arriba.columna, elementosRecorridos)
    if nodoActual.abajo != None:
        self.ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(nodoActual.abajo.fila, nodoActual.abajo.columna, elementosRecorridos)```
````

Comment: Cambia el `print(type(nodoActual.derecha)` por `print(type(nodoActual)` para ver que es `nodoActual`. Parece que `getNodo` retorna un string ...

Comment: El `print(type(nodoActual)` me devuelve `<class 'NodoPosicion.NodoPosicion'>`
mientras que el `print(type(nodoActual.derecha))` me devuelve `<class 'str'>` cuando en realidad también debería ser un `<class 'NodoPosicion.NodoPosicion'>`

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado el error y básicamente se encontraba en la forma recursiva de mi código por lo que el `<class 'str'>` que me devolvía antes en el `print(type(nodoActual.derecha))` era que mi atributo `.fila` sí es un *String* realmente, por lo que solo necesitaba castearlo para que cuando llamase a mi función otra vez de forma recursiva en los `if()` no se estuvieran mandando un **str** sino un variable de tipo **int**.

Aquí dejo mi solución de igual forma por si a alguien en algún momento le sirve:

```
    #Función para recorrer todo mi matriz de nodos desde un nodo cualquiera elegido
    def ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(self, origenFila, origenColumna, elementosRecorridos = []):
        nodoActual = self.getNodo(origenFila, origenColumna)
        if nodoActual in elementosRecorridos:
            return
        print("Nodo en la fila: ", nodoActual.fila, "Nodo en la columna: ", nodoActual.columna)
        elementosRecorridos.append(nodoActual)
        #Vecinos del grafo/nodo en la matriz
        if nodoActual.derecha != None:
            self.ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(int(nodoActual.derecha.fila), int(nodoActual.derecha.columna), elementosRecorridos)
        if nodoActual.izquierda != None:
            self.ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(int(nodoActual.izquierda.fila), int(nodoActual.izquierda.columna), elementosRecorridos)
        if nodoActual.arriba != None:
            self.ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(int(nodoActual.arriba.fila), int(nodoActual.arriba.columna), elementosRecorridos)
        if nodoActual.abajo != None:
            self.ProfundidadPrimeroMatriz(int(nodoActual.abajo.fila), int(nodoActual.abajo.columna), elementosRecorridos)
```